# How work jquery ui tabs using option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Is there a way to use option selected as Tab selector in [Jquery ui tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/).
I use Javascript to make select options looks like standard tab selectors but couldn`t inject to jquery tabs to replace original HTML lists selectors.

```
<div id="tabs">

  <select class="feature-select">
    <option rel="#tab-1" selected="" value="">Tab 1</option>
    <option rel="#tab-2" value="">Tab 2</option>
  </select>

  <div id="tab-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
      leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum.
      Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
      leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum.
      Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0e2cxeL2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a change handler(but need to modify the segment plugin as given below) then toggle the display in that change handler like

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    Segment: function() {
      $(this).each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        var wrapper = $("<div>", {
          class: "ui-segment"
        });
        $(this).find("option").each(function() {
          var option = $("<span>", {
            class: 'option',
            text: $(this).text(),
            value: $(this).val()
          });
          if ($(this).is(":selected")) {
            option.addClass("active");
          }
          wrapper.append(option);
        });
        wrapper.find("span.option").click(function() {
          wrapper.find("span.option").removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
          self.val($(this).attr('value')).change(); //minor change here to trigger the change event on click
        });
        $(this).after(wrapper);
        $(this).hide();
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);


$(function() {
  $(".feature-select").Segment();
  $(".feature-select").change(function() {
    var $selected = this.value ? $(this.value).show() : $();
    $('#tabs > .tab').not($selected).hide();
  }).change()
});
```

```css
.ui-segment {
  color: #3599B0;
  border: 1px solid #3599B0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Lato', Georgia, Serif;
}
.ui-segment span.option.active {
  background-color: #3599B0;
  color: white;
}
.ui-segment span.option {
  padding-left: 23px;
  padding-right: 23px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-right: 1px solid #3599B0;
}
.ui-segment span.option:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.segment-select {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <select class="feature-select">
    <option selected="" value="#tab-1">Tab 1</option>
    <option value="#tab-2">Tab 2</option>
  </select>
  <div id="tab-1" class="tab">
    <p>1. Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
      leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum.
      Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab">
    <p>2. Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
      leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum.
      Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```